# SML- how to look at a string and put letters a-z into a list (only once)

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

I have seen some similar questions, but nothing that really helped me. Basically the title says it all. Using SML I want to take a string that I have, and make a list containing each letter found in the string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of all the letters in a few different ways:

```
val letters = [#"a",#"b",#"c",#"d",#"e",#"f",#"g",#"h",#"i",#"j",#"k",#"l",#"m",#"n",#"o",#"p",#"q",#"r",#"s",#"t",#"u",#"v",#"w",#"x",#"y",#"z"]
val letters = explode "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
val letters = List.tabulate (26, fn i => chr (i + ord #"a"))
```

---

**Update:** Looking at your question and John's answer, I might have misunderstood your intention. An efficient way to iterate over a string and gather some result (e.g. a set of characters) could be to write a "foldr for strings":

```
fun string_foldr f acc0 s =
    let val len = size s
        fun loop i acc = if i < len then loop (i+1) (f (String.sub (s, i), acc)) else acc
        in loop 0 acc0 end
```

Given an implementation of sets with at least `setEmpty` and `setInsert`, one could then write:

```
val setLetters = string_foldr (fn (c, ls) => setInsert ls c) setEmpty "some sentence"
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the basic logic of quicksort to sort the letters while removing duplicates at the same time. Something like:

```
fun distinctChars []:char list = []
|   distinctChars (c::cs) =
       let val smaller = List.filter (fn x => x < c) cs
           val bigger = List.filter (fn x => x > c) cs
       in distinctChars smaller @ [c] @ distinctChars bigger
       end
```

If the `<` and `>` in the definitions of `smaller` and `bigger` were to be replaced by `<=` and `>=` then it would simply be an implementation of quicksort (although not the most efficient one since it makes two passes over `cs` when a suitably defined auxiliary function could split into smaller and bigger in just one pass). The strict inequalities have the effect of throwing away duplicates.

To get what you want from here, do something like explode the string into a list of chars, remove non-alphabetical characters from the resulting list, while simultaneously converting to lower case, then invoke the above function -- ideally first refined so that it uses a custom `split` function rather than `List.filter` twice.

On Edit: `@` is an expensive operator and probably results in the naïve SML quicksort not being all that quick. You can use the above idea of a modified sort, but one that modifies mergesort instead of quicksort:

```
fun split ls = 
    let fun split' [] (xs,ys) = (xs,ys)
        |   split' (a::[]) (xs, ys) = (a::xs,ys)
        |   split' (a::b::cs) (xs, ys) = split' cs (a::xs, b::ys)
    in split' ls ([],[])
    end

fun mergeDistinct ([], ys) = ys:char list
|   mergeDistinct (xs, []) = xs
|   mergeDistinct (x::xs, y::ys) = 
        if x < y then x::mergeDistinct(xs,y::ys)
        else if x > y then y::mergeDistinct(x::xs,ys)
        else mergeDistinct(x::xs, ys)

fun distinctChars [] = []
|   distinctChars [c] = [c]
|   distinctChars chars =
        let val (xs,ys) = split chars
        in mergeDistinct (distinctChars xs, distinctChars ys)
        end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me and it removed dups. Is there a way to check that they are only letters a-z though? It still keeps comas, spaces etc in the list.

Comment: `Char.isAlpha` checks if a character is alphabetic and `Char.toLower` can be used to convert a character to lower case. I would probably write a function which takes a string, explodes it to a list of characters, and then builds up a second list of characters which consists of the alphabetic characters in the first list, converted to lower case. Alternatively, if you are familiar with `map` and `List.filter` you could map `toLower` and then filter with `isAlpha`.

Comment: Thanks, does Char.isAlpha return true for alt codes and other such things or strictly letters a-z?

Comment: @Kasarrah: Why don't you [find out](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/Char.sml#L56)? :)

Comment: @Kasarrah I assume that `Char.isAlpha` simply tests the character with inequalities involving  #"a", #"z", #"A", and #"Z"

Comment: @SimonShine Thanks for providing the link to the source. I haven't done so with the MoscowML source but I've found that looking at the SML/NJ implementations of some of the standard basis to be a good educational experience.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of:

To get the distinct elements of a list:

1. Take the head
2. Remove that value from the tail and get the distinct elements of the result.
3. Put 1 and 2 together.

In code:

```
(* Return the distinct elements of a list *)
fun distinct [] = []
  | distinct (x::xs) = x :: distinct (List.filter (fn c => x <> c) xs); 

(* All the distinct letters, in lower case. *)
fun letters s = distinct (List.map Char.toLower (List.filter Char.isAlpha (explode s)));

(* Variation: "point-free" style *)
val letters' = distinct o (List.map Char.toLower) o (List.filter Char.isAlpha) o explode;
```

This is probably not the most efficient solution, but it's uncomplicated.

Comment: I like your point-free version. None of these are efficient but you can't beat their length.